# The SVG file doesn't show the hover effect when I place it in the HTML hot spot section

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I created an SVG map where each corresponding element displays a specific effect upon hovering. Styles are embedded within the SVG. [Link to the map:](https://hoffmannteile.de/data/include/cms/modyfikacje/Mapa/hoffmannmap-01.svg)

I want to use it as a background for hotspots, but after inserting it as an img, the hover effect doesn't work. The same issue persists when inserted as an SVG. Any ideas?

Here is the code for the section:

```
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .map-section {
      background-color: transparent;
      padding: 20px;
      min-height: 800px;
      max-width: 1200px;
    }

    .map-container {
      position: relative;
    }

    .hotspots {
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .hotspot {
      height: 18px;
      width: 18px;
      background-color: #ad0000;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      animation: pulsate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    }

    /*schweiz*/
    .hot1{
      top: 90%;
      left: 18%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*belgien*/
    .hot2{
      top: 39.5%;
      left: 11.5%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*niederlande*/
    .hot3{
      top: 27.5%;
      left: 11.5%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*osterreich*/
    .hot4{
      top: 83%;
      left: 52%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*deutschland*/
    .hot5{
      top: 42%;
      left: 53.5%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*polen*/
    .hot6{
      top: 38%;
      left: 74%;
      position: absolute;
    }

    /* styles for SVG elements */
    .schweiz, .belgien, .niederlande, .ostrreich, .deutschland, .polen {
      fill: #FFFFFF;
      stroke: #610000;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      transition: fill 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    }

    .schweiz:hover, .belgien:hover, .niederlande:hover, .ostrreich:hover, .deutschland:hover, .polen:hover {
      fill: #ad0000;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .noclick {
      fill: #E8E8E8;
      stroke: #7A0000;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }

    @keyframes pulsate {
      0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
      }
      50% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
      }
    }
  </style>

 <section class="map-section">
    <div class="map-container">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 498.1 315.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 498.1 315.8;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g id="Layer_3">
            <path class="schweiz" d="M101.8,256.1c1.4,1.4,2.8,2.4,3.3,2.8l-0.1-3l6.6,2.7l3.5-0.2c5-0.2,10.6-0.5,15.6-0.7c0.3,0,6.5-0.3,6.6-0.3
                c0,0.3,0.2,3.2,0.2,3.4c1.7,0,4.6-0.2,6.2-0.2l0.1,2.9c1.4,0.6,4.3,1.9,5.7,2.5v2.9l-3.1,3.3l0.2,3.2c3.4,2,2.9,0.9,2.2,4.8
                c1.4,0.1,4.1-0.5,5.5-0.9c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1-0.1c1.5,0.9,4.4,3.5,5.7,4.8l9-0.4h0.7c0.1,2.9,0.3,6.8,0.4,9.7l-3.2,0.2l-3.3-2.8
                c-1.6,1.7-4.5,4.8-6.2,6.4c0.5,0.4,3.2,2.7,3.6,3c-4.1,3.7-2.1,4.1-6.5,0.3c-2.9,0.1-6.8,0.3-9.6,0.4c0-0.4-0.1-2.7-0.2-3.2
                l-0.5-0.5c-2.9-2.6-1.8-2.8-5.9-2.4c0,2,0.4,7.2,0.5,9.3l-3.5,0.1l-2.8,3.5l-3.3,3.2l0.2,3.1c-2.8-2.8-7-6.1-9.7-9.1
                c0-1.5-0.2-4.6-0.3-6.1c-0.4-0.4-3-2.6-3.4-3l-3.2,0.2l-3.1,3.3l0.2,3.2l-3.1,6.5l-3,0.2l-6.2,0.3l-3.5-3.2l-12.5,3.9
                c-1.8-1.8-4.6-4.3-6.5-6c0-3.8-1-3.1,2.8-3.3l-3.1-3l-0.1-3c1.7,0,4.4-0.2,6.2-0.2l-0.2-3.4l-3.5-6c-0.8,0-2.2,0.1-3,0.1l0.2,3.2
                c-0.4,0-3.1,0.2-3.5,0.2c-3.2,7.7-1.3,5.8-8.8,9.6c-0.3,0.6-3.5-6.2-3.7-6.1l2.9-6.3l6.1-6.4l-0.2-3.2l2.8-3.3l6.5-0.3l6.2-3.5
                l2.7-6.3l-0.2-3.2c0.1,0.1,3.3-3.6,3.4-3.2c1.6,1.6,4.9,4.5,6.6,5.9l0.1-0.3l2.6-6.2c0,0,3.2,2.9,3.4,3c0-0.2-0.2-2.9-0.2-3.2
                L101.8,256.1z"/>
            <path class="belgien" d="M71.1,181.4l-2-3.5c-0.1-1.6-0.3-4.8-0.3-6.4l3.2-3.1l3-3.6c0.3-0.3,2.7-0.3,3.1-0.3c-0.1-2.2-0.3-4.9-0.4-7.1
                c4.5-0.2,3,0.5,3-3.7c-0.2-3.8,0.5-2.9-3.2-2.8l2.8-6c0-2.5-0.3-6-0.4-8.5h-0.1l-0.2-3l-6.8-6.1c-1.7-1.5-5.2-4.6-6.8-6.1l-3.4,0.1
                l-3,3.1c0,0-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3l-3.6,0.1l-0.1-3.2L45.5,119c0-0.3-2.8,0-2.9,0l-3.2,3.1l0.2,3.2c-2.3,0.1-7.9,0.4-10.1,0.5
                c-4,0.1-2.9,0.8-3.3-3.1l-3.5-2.8l-3.4,0.2l-0.2-3.5l-3.4,0.2l-3.2,3.6L9,117.1l0.2,3.4l-6.3,3.2l0.1,3.2c0.1,1.6,0.3,4.6,0.3,6.2
                l3.3,3c0.4,0,0.3,2.3,0.3,2.6v0.7l3.1-0.2l3.1-0.1h0.2c0.1,1.7,0.2,4.7,0.3,6.4c1.6-0.1,4.9-0.2,6.5-0.3c0.4-0.3,0.2,2.9,0.3,3v0.3
                l3.7,6.1c2.9-0.2,6.9-0.2,9.8-0.5c0.1,2.1,0.4,7.6,0.5,9.7l-3,2.9l-0.2,0.2l3.5,3.3c1.7-0.1,5-0.2,6.7-0.3l-0.2-3.5l3.4-0.2
                l0.1,3.5l3.3,2.7l0.2,0.2c0,0.3,0.1,3,0.2,3.2l3.3,2.9l0.2,0.2l0.1,2.4v0.6l3.2-0.1c1.7,1.6,5.2,4.7,7,6.1l0.2,3.2l3.2-3.4l3.4-0.1
                l0.7-0.4C69.7,187.2,71.3,181.5,71.1,181.4z"/>
            <path class="noclick" d="M82.7,188.4c3.9-0.2,2.9,0.4,2.8-3.3c-0.1-1.8-0.2-4.5-0.3-6.3c-0.1-0.7-0.1-2.7-0.2-3.4
                c-1.7-1.5-5.1-4.5-6.7-6c0-1.2-0.2-3.7-0.2-4.9l-2.6,0.1c-0.4-0.3-3.3,3.6-3.5,3.8l-3.2,3.1c0.1,1.6,0.2,4.8,0.3,6.4l2,3.5
                c0.1,0.1-1.5,5.8-0.8,5.5c3.9,0.8,9.3,2.5,13.3,3C83.4,189.5,83,188.8,82.7,188.4z"/>
            <path class="niederlande" d="M55.8,121.5l0.1,3.2c0.2-0.1,3.9,0.1,3.8-0.4l2.8-3.1h0.2l3.4-0.1l3.3,3c2.3,1.9,8,7.1,10.3,9.2l0.2,3
                c0.2,0.1,0-1,0.1-1c0.2-0.3,6.3-2.9,5.8-3.5l0.5-0.2l-0.2-3.2c-0.1-3.4-0.4-8.7-0.6-12.1l5.9-3.4l9.5-3.5l3.1,2.9
                c2.9-0.1,6.8-0.3,9.6-0.5l3.2-0.1l0.1-0.4c0.3,0.1,2.7-9.4,2.9-9.5l-0.2-3.2l-3.1-2.8L119,93c-0.2-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.4-0.7
                c-0.1-3.3-0.5-8.7-0.6-12l3-0.2v-0.4h0.2c-0.1-2.7-0.4-6.4-0.5-9.1l2.7-3.1l0,0l0.4-0.4l-2.1-1.8l-2.6,2.4l-3.2,0.2l-0.6-12.7
                c-1.7,0.1-5,0.2-6.7,0.3l-3,3.6l-6.6,3.3c-0.1-1.6-0.2-4.9-0.3-6.5l-3.4,3.6L93,59.6l-3.4,0.2L83,63.1l-3.2,3.4
                c0.1,1.5,0.2,4.6,0.3,6.2c0.1,3.6,0.5,9.2,0.7,12.9l-6.2,6.5c-1.7,0-5,0.2-6.7,0.3l-0.3-6.2l3.2-3.5l-3.4,0.1
                c1.6-1.6,4.8-4.9,6.4-6.5l-0.2-3.2L70,70c-9,0.4-5.5-0.9-9.8,6.8l0.3,6.2l-3,3.5l0.1,3L54,89.7l0.2,3.2l-3,3.4l-6.7,0.3l0.3,6.4
                c3.8,0,3.3-1.4,3.5,2.8l-6.3,3.5l-0.3-6.2l-3.6,0.2c0.1,3.4,0.5,8.9,0.6,12.4l3.6-0.2l3.1,3.1l0.2,0.2L55.8,121.5z"/>
            <path class="ostrreich" d="M327.1,244.9L327.1,244.9h0.2l2.3-1.1c0-0.4-3.6-4-3.9-4.4l0.9-2.8c-2.5-3.5-1.6-2.6-5.7-2.5
                c-0.8-0.2-2.5-0.5-3.2-0.7l-5-2.3l-1-1.9l-2-1.8l-1.8-2.7c-2.1-0.3-7.4,0.3-9.5,0.3c-0.7-0.5-2.9-2.7-3.7-3
                c-3.5,0.2-9,0.4-12.5,0.6c-0.8,0.7-2.4,2.3-2.8,3.3l0.1,3.2l-3,3.3c-3.1,0.1-9.5,0.4-12.7,0.6l-1.3-0.6l-2.4-2.2
                c-0.6-0.2-2.5-0.1-3.1-0.1l0.2,3.2c-2.9,0.1-6.9,0.4-9.8,0.5l0.1,3c-1.4,1.6-4.3,5-5.7,6.6l-9.9,0.4c0.1,2,0.4,7.3,0.5,9.3
                c0.7,0.6,3,2.7,3.6,3.3l0.1,2.9l0.2,3.2c0.5,0.5,2.7,2.6,3.1,3c0.1,1.6,0.3,4.8,0.3,6.3l-3,0.2l0.2,3l-0.9-0.7v0.1
                c-0.4-0.4-2.2-1.8-2.7-2.2c-0.1-1.6-0.2-4.7-0.3-6.3c-0.1-0.1-6-2.7-6.3-2.9l-3,0.1l0.2,3.2l-3.6-3c-3.5,0.2-9.2,0.4-12.7,0.6
                l-3.1,3.3l-3,0.1l-3.4,0.2l-3.2-3l-3.2,3.3c-1.6,0.1-4.8,0.2-6.5,0.3c0-0.6-0.2-2.6-0.1-3.2c0,0-5.9-2.8-6.2-2.9l-3.2,6.5l-3,0.1
                c-4.2,3.6-2.1,4.2-6.5,0.3L163,269c-0.4-0.4-1.2-1-1.5-1.4c-1.2-1-4-3.6-5.2-4.6l-3.2,0.2l-2.9,3.3l-0.9-0.4v2.9l0.8-0.1l2.7,3.1
                l-0.7,2.2l2.4,1.2l-0.3,3.8c1.5,0.9,4.4,3.5,5.7,4.8c2.6-0.1,10.2-0.5,12.7-0.6c0.2,0,3.1-0.1,3.2-0.1c0.1,1.7,0.3,4.6,0.3,6.3
                c1.6-0.1,4.8-0.2,6.5-0.3l6-3.4l-0.2-3.2l3.2-0.2l3.4,3c2.9-0.1,6.8-0.4,9.7-0.5l6.2-0.3c1.6,1.4,4.7,4.3,6.3,5.7l0.5,0.4l0.2,3
                l3.2,3c0.6,0.6,2.8,2.2,3.5,2.8c1.6-0.1,4.7-0.2,6.2-0.3c2.1-0.1,7.4-0.3,9.6-0.4c0.8,0.8,2.5,2.4,3.4,3.2l2.8-0.2
                c0.2,0,0.7,0,0.8,0.2l5.5-1.9l2.8-0.1l3.9,4.2c1.8-0.1,4.6-0.2,6.4-0.3l3.8,2.6l0.7-2.8l4.4-1.9l3.9,0.7c-0.5-0.6,2.1-5,2.3-5.6
                h0.6c4-0.2,8.9-0.4,12.9-0.6c2.7,0.2,5.8-1.2,8.3-2.1l3.7,0.7l4-3.5c0.1-0.1,2.2-5.4,2.5-5c-0.1-0.3,2.9-0.2,3-0.3l2.6-6.3
                l-0.3-6.1h0.5v-0.4c3.4-0.4,3.1,0.9,2.9-2.9l-0.2-3l-3.6-3l-0.2-3.2h0.4V261c0.5,0,3.5-0.1,3.8-0.2l2.9-1.6l-0.5,1.5
                c0.3-0.2,0.1,1.2,0.2,1.2l3.2,0.7c0-0.2-0.4-1.8-0.1-1.9v-0.2l2.6-3c-1.4-3.4-3-8.8-5.2-11.7L327.1,244.9z"/>
            <path class="noclick" d="M146.3,272.2l0.2,3.2c3.4,2,2.9,0.9,2.2,4.8c1.4,0.1,4.2-0.5,5.6-0.9c0-0.1,0.3-3.8,0.3-3.9l-2.4-1.2l0.7-2.2
                l-2.7-3.1l-0.8,0.1C149.4,268.9,146.3,272.2,146.3,272.2z"/>
            <path class="deutschland" d="M102.5,256.7c0.5,0.5,2.1,1.8,2.6,2.2l-0.1-3l6.6,2.7l3.5-0.2c5-0.2,10.6-0.5,15.6-0.7c0.3,0,6.5-0.3,6.6-0.3
                c0,0.3,0.2,3.2,0.2,3.4c1.7,0,4.5-0.2,6.2-0.2l0.1,2.9c1.8,0.8,4.8,2.1,6.6,2.9l2.9-3.3l3.2-0.2c1.5,1.4,4.3,3.9,5.8,5.2l0.9,0.8
                l3.2-0.1c4.4,3.9,2.2,3.3,6.5-0.3l3-0.1l3.2-6.5c0.3,0.1,6.1,2.9,6.2,2.9c-0.1,0.6,0.2,2.6,0.1,3.2c1.6-0.1,4.8-0.2,6.5-0.3
                l3.2-3.3l3.2,3l3.4-0.2l3-0.1l3.1-3.3c3.5-0.1,9.2-0.4,12.7-0.6l3.6,3l-0.2-3.2l3-0.1c0.3,0.2,6.2,2.8,6.3,2.9
                c0,1.6,0.2,4.7,0.3,6.3c1,0.8,2.7,2.1,3.6,2.8l-0.2-3c4.1-0.2,2.8,0.3,2.8-3.5l-0.2-3l-0.6-0.6l-2.5-2.4c-0.1-1.5-0.2-4.6-0.3-6.1
                c-0.6-0.6-3.1-2.7-3.6-3.3c-0.1-1.9-0.3-7.3-0.5-9.3l9.9-0.4c1.4-1.7,4.3-5,5.7-6.6l-0.1-3c2.9-0.1,6.9-0.3,9.8-0.5l-0.2-3.2
                l-2-2.6l-3-3.7c-1.5-1-4-3.4-5-4.9l-0.3-0.4l-3.1,0.1l-3.3-2.8c-1.8-3-5.3-9.1-7-12.2l-3.9-3.1c0.2-2.1-0.3-6.9-0.6-9l-2.5-3.5
                l-3.8-2.5l-0.3-6.4l-2.6-0.2l-4.1-5.6l-0.4-7c0.5-0.3,3.6,2.9,3.9,3.2l0.2,3.2l5.9-3.6c0.2-0.1,3.4,3,3.6,3.2l5.9-0.6l0.3-0.1
                l4.2-2.8l1.8-0.7c0.3,0,3.2,0,3.4-0.1l2.3-3.9l3.9-0.2l8.4-5.9c1.8-1.4,4.9-4.5,6.3-6.3l6.7-3.6c0.3,0.1,3.4,3,3.8,3.2l0.2,3.2
                l2.6-0.3c0-0.2,3.1-3.2,3.2-3.4c-0.1-1.8-0.5-10.3-0.6-12.2l2.8-3.3c-3.6,0-2.9,1-3.1-2.8c-0.2-3.9-0.6-11.7-0.7-15.7l-3.8-6.2
                l-0.1-3.2L276,104l3.3-3.3l-3.2,0.1h-0.2l-3.1-3l-0.1-3l-3.4-3l-3.6-6.2c1.7-1.5,4.7-4.8,6.2-6.6c-0.1-1.5-0.2-4.6-0.3-6.1
                c-0.3-4.5-0.2-10.8-0.5-15.4l-9.7,0.4l-0.3-6.4l-0.3-6.3c-2.2,0.2-7.5,0.3-9.6,0.5l-0.2-3.2l-3.2-2.8c-0.2-4.2,0.5-3.1-3.5-3
                l-2.9,3.3c-1.6,0.1-4.9,0.2-6.5,0.3c-3.2,1.6-9.5,4.9-12.5,6.7l-3.2-3l0.2,3.2c-3.6,0.1-9.3,0.4-12.9,0.6l-6.6-2.9l3.5-0.2
                c-0.1-3.7-0.7-2.8,2.9-3.1c-0.1-1.6-0.2-4.9-0.3-6.5c-1.6,0.1-4.9,0.2-6.5,0.3l-2.8,3.5l-3.5-6.2c-1.6,0.1-4.8,0.2-6.4,0.3
                l-0.2-3.2c-1.6,0.1-4.8,0.2-6.4,0.3l-0.2-3.2l3.2-3.3c-1.8-1.4-5.3-4.3-6.9-5.9l-1-0.8l-1.4,1.3l1.3-1.4l-2.2-1.7
                c-0.1-0.1-5.8,0.5-5.6,0h-0.6l-2.9-2.6l-2.8,0.1c0-0.9-0.2-0.6-0.9-0.6c0.1,2.1,0.3,7.5,0.5,9.5l3.1,2.8l0.2,3.2l-6.3,3.5l-3,0.1
                c0.3,3.8-0.8,3.2,3.2,3c0.1,1.6,0.2,4.8,0.3,6.3l6.6,2.9l-2.8,3.1l2.5,1.8l3.4,4.8l-1.7,3.4l-1.7-2.9l-1.5-3.1
                c-3.1,0.2-7.5-0.5-10.6-0.4c0.2,3.6,0.4,9.2,0.6,12.7l-3,3.3l0.1,2.9l-3.5-5.7c-0.1-1.6-0.2-4.8-0.3-6.4l-3.2,0.1l0.2,3.2l-3,0.1
                l-0.2-3.2l2.9-3.3l-6.6-2.9c-4.6,0.2-11.3,0.5-15.8,0.7l0.2,3.2l-3.1,3.3c0.3,4-0.6,3.1,3.4,3l0.2,3.2c0.8,0.6,2.6,2.1,3.3,2.8
                l-0.4,0.4l0,0l-2.7,3.1c0.1,2.7,0.3,6.4,0.5,9.1h-0.2V80l-3,0.2c0.1,3.3,0.5,8.7,0.6,12l-0.4,0.5v0.2l-2.5,2.8l3.1,2.8l0.2,3.2
                l-2.7,9.4c-0.2,0-0.2,0.4-0.2,0.5c-4,0.2-8.8,0.4-12.8,0.6l-3.1-2.9l-9.5,3.5l-5.9,3.4l0.2,2.8c0.1,3.5,0.4,9,0.6,12.4l-0.5,0.2
                v0.4l-5.8,3.1v1c0.1,2.5,0.3,6,0.4,8.5l-2.8,6c3.7,0,3-1,3.2,2.8c-0.1,4.2,1.5,3.6-3,3.7c0.2,3.9,0.4,8.1,0.6,12
                c1.6,1.5,5.1,4.5,6.7,6.1c0.2,3,0.3,6.6,0.5,9.7c0,3.7,1.2,3.1-2.8,3.3c1.9,3.1,5,8.6,6.8,11.7l3.4,3l6.3,2.9l6.7-0.3l3.1,2.8
                c1.6-0.1,4.9-0.2,6.5-0.3l3,3l0.3,0.3c-2.1,2.3-7.1,7.6-9.2,9.7l-2.7,6.5l0.1,3l-3.3,3.3c0.1,2,0.4,7.2,0.5,9.2l0.2,3.2l-3.1,3.3
                c0.1,1.6,0.2,4.7,0.3,6.2l0.2,0.1L102.5,256.7z"/>
            <path class="polen" d="M492.1,148.9l-2.4-1l-0.2-4l2.3-1.2l-5.9-6.9l-2.5-4.6l-4.7-3c2.1-3.2,2-2-0.2-5l1.7-9.2
                c-0.3-0.3-0.8-0.9-1.1-1.2c-0.5-1.3,1.3-10.2,1.5-11.7l-5.7-1l-2.7-3.7l11.4-8.4c0-0.4,1.2-3.1,1.2-3.4l0.7-2.2
                c-0.2-2.2-0.1-11-1.5-12.8l-1.2-3.4c-1.2-1.4-4.5-5.5-5.7-7l-1.9-2.2l-0.4-9.1l-2.5-2l-1.3-4.6c0-1-0.3-5.8-0.3-6.7l-7.1-5l-4.8-1
                l-5.6-3.5L453,25c-0.1,0,2.1-3.6,2.2-3.7l-3.5,0.2l1-0.5l0.9-4.5c-0.5-2.2-1.3-6-2.5-8l-2.6-5.2l-5.7-1.7l-5,1.9L435.2,7l-1.1,1.3
                c-2.4,0.1-7.8,0.4-10.1,0.5h-0.8l-1-2.5l-2.7-3.5c-1.8,0.5-6,1.4-7.9,1.2c0.2,4-0.3,2.8,3.4,2.8l-2.9,6.3l-3.1,3.3l-6.2,0.3
                c-0.2-2.8-0.3-6.6-0.5-9.3L393,14l0.2,3.2l-5.4,4.7l5.7,1.7l0.2,2.9l-3,3.5l-3,0.2c0.2,2.7,0.3,6.5,0.5,9.2
                c-2.1,0.1-7.6,0.3-9.7,0.5l-0.1-3.2l-3.2,0.1l-9.3,3.6l-3.5-3c-0.2-2.8-0.3-6.7-0.5-9.5l-3.2-2.8l-0.2-3.2l-9.7,0.5l-3,3.3
                l-3.2,0.2l-6.4-2.9l-3,3.3l-3.2,0.2c0.2,4,0.5,2.7-3.1,3.1l-3.1,3.5l-3.4-3.2c-1.3,1.8-4.3,5.2-5.9,6.8l-3,3.1l-3.2,0.2l-3,3.3
                l-3.2,0.2c0,3.8,1.1,3.1-2.9,3.3c-2.1,0.1-7.6,0.3-9.7,0.5l-6.2,3.5l-2.9,6.5l-2.8,3.1l3.1,2.8l0.2,3.4l-0.9-0.4l-4.7,0.2l-3.6-4.2
                c-0.4,5.5,0.2,11.6,0.4,17.1c-1.4,1.8-4.5,5.1-6.2,6.6l3.6,6.2l3.4,3l0.1,3l3.1,3h0.2l3.2-0.1l-3.5,3l0.2,3.2l0.1,3.2l3.8,6.2
                c0.2,4,0.6,11.7,0.7,15.7c0.2,3.7-0.6,2.9,3.1,2.8l-2.8,3.3c0.1,2,0.5,10.4,0.6,12.2c0.3-0.2,1.4-1.8,1.6-2.2
                c0.1,0,4.5-0.9,4.6-0.9l3.1-0.1c0.1,3.5,0.5,8.8,0.6,12.2l3.2-0.2l3.4,3l3.2-0.2l6.4,2.9h0.4l6-0.3l3.4,3c-1.5,1.7-4.6,5-6.1,6.6
                h0.5l6-0.3c0.1-0.1,3.3,2.8,3.4,2.8l3.5,6c0-0.5-0.5-3.1-0.6-3.6l0.8-1.6l2.4-1.5l3.3,0.4l-3.4-1.3l-0.3-2c2.3,0.6,7.6,0,10,0
                l3.4,2.8c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.7,0.4-0.9l2.7-2.4c2,2.7,7.3,10.3,10,12.2l6.6,2.7l6.4-0.3l3.2,3c1.7,1.5,5.1,4.3,6.7,5.8h0.4l6-0.2
                l3.4,3.2c0.3-0.1,0-1.5,0.1-1.7l2.7-2.5l2.4-1.2c0.2-0.1,4.3-1.2,4.2-1.5l0.1,0.1l3.1,2.7l0.3,6.3l0.4-0.4v-1l1.8-1.6l-0.1-4.4l7-3
                l3.3,3.5l3-0.1l3.1-3.1c0.1,2,0.3,7.3,0.4,9.2c0.3,0.3,6.5-4.3,6.8-4.5l4-0.4c1-1.2,3.5-3.9,4.6-5.1l3.7,6.2h0.2l2.8-0.1
                c3.1,2.5,7.1,6.2,10.1,8.8c0.9,0,2.3-0.1,3.2-0.1c1.3-0.1,4-0.2,5.3-0.2h0.9l1.2,4.6c0.8-1.2,2.4-3.6,3.2-4.8l-0.4-3.3l0.7-2.6
                c-0.1-1.6-0.2-4.8-0.3-6.3c0.4-2.6,1.5-8.4,2.3-10.9l2.6-3.7l3.4-1c1-2.2,3.2-7.1,4.3-9.1l6.2-5.8l6.2,0.5l3.5-2.7l2-6.9
                L492.1,148.9z"/>
            <path class="noclick" d="M278.7,153.6c0.1,0.3-2.7,0.4-2.8,0.5l-0.2-3.2c-0.2-0.3-3.7-3-3.8-3.2l-6.7,3.6c-1.4,1.8-4.5,4.9-6.3,6.3
                l-8.4,5.9l-3.9,0.2l-2.3,3.9c-0.2,0.1-3.1,0.1-3.4,0.1l-1.8,0.7l-4.2,2.8l-0.3,0.1l-5.9,0.6c-0.2-0.2-3.3-3.3-3.6-3.2l-5.9,3.6
                l-0.2-3.2c-0.3-0.2-3.5-3.4-3.9-3.2l0.4,7l4.1,5.6l2.6,0.2l0.3,6.4l3.8,2.5l2.5,3.5c0.4,2.2,0.7,6.9,0.6,9l3.9,3.1
                c1.7,3.1,5.2,9.2,7,12.2l3.3,2.8l3.1-0.1c0.1,0.2,2.2,2.7,2.4,2.9c2.9,2,5.8,5.9,7.9,8.7c0.2,0.1,3-0.1,3.1,0.1l2.4,2.2
                c0.9,1,6.4,0.3,7.5,0.3l6.4-0.3l3-3.3l-0.1-3.2c0.4-1,2-2.6,2.8-3.3c3.6-0.2,9.1-0.4,12.7-0.6c0.5,0.5,3,2.5,3.5,3
                c2.1-0.1,7.3-0.4,9.4-0.5c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1l1.8,2.7l2,1.8l1,1.9c1,0.5,5.8,2.7,6.9,2.7l2.4-5.6l0.4-5l2.6-4.3
                c2.5-1,7.5-2.7,10.1-3.3l6.6-5l3-0.9l3.2,1.2c1.8,1.8,5.7,4.3,7.9,5.4l3.9-0.1l4.5-3.5c1.7-3,5.4-8.9,7.3-11.8l3.6-3.1l1-1.7
                l-2.9-2.6c-1.8-1.4-5.1-4.5-6.7-6l-6.4,0.3l-6.6-2.7c-2.6-1.9-8.1-9.5-10-12.2l-2.7,2.4c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.8-0.4,0.9l-3.4-2.8
                c-2.4,0-7.7,0.7-10,0l0.3,2l3.4,1.3l-3.3-0.4l-2.4,1.5l-0.8,1.6c0.1,0.5,0.6,3.1,0.6,3.6l-3.5-6c0,0-3.3-2.9-3.4-2.8l-6,0.3h-0.5
                c1.5-1.6,4.6-5,6.1-6.6l-3.4-3l-6,0.3h-0.4l-6.4-2.9L298,162l-3.4-3l-3.2,0.2c-0.1-3.4-0.4-8.8-0.6-12.2c-1.9-0.1-5.8,0.6-7.7,1
                C282.5,149.9,279.9,152.3,278.7,153.6z"/>
            <path class="noclick" d="M459.6,205.2c-2.9,0.1-6.3,0.3-9.2,0.4c-1.9-1.1-5.2-4.6-7-6l-3.3-2.8l-2.8,0.1c-0.3,0.5-3.8-6.2-4-6.2
                c-1.1,1.2-3.6,3.9-4.6,5.1l-4,0.4l-6,4.3l-0.4,0.3v-0.1l-0.5,0.1c-0.1-1.9-0.3-7.3-0.4-9.2l-3.1,3.1l-3,0.1l-3.3-3.5l-7,3l0.1,4.4
                l-1.8,1.6v1l-0.4,0.4l-0.3-6.3c-0.2-0.1-3.2-3.1-3.4-2.6c-1.6,0.4-5,1.5-6.4,2.4l-2.7,2.5c0,0.2,0.2,1.5-0.1,1.7l-3.4-3.2
                c-0.3-0.1-6.7,0.5-6.6,0.1l-1,1.7l-3.6,3.1l-4,6.2l-3.3,5.5l-4.5,3.5l-3.9,0.1c-2.3-1.1-6.1-3.6-7.9-5.4l-3.2-1.2l-3,0.9l-6.6,5
                c-2.6,0.5-7.7,2.3-10.1,3.3l-2.6,4.3l-0.4,5l-2.4,5.6c0.9,0.5,4.1,0.2,5.1,0.1l2,2.7l-0.9,2.8c0.4,0.4,3.7,4,4.1,4.3
                c-1.2,0.6-3.4,1.5-4.6,2.1l1.5,2.2l-0.6-1.4l7.3,4.7l0.5,0.4h0.9l3.1,2.6l2.2-0.1c1.7,1.3,4.9,4.2,6.4,5.7c0.1,0.4,6.1-0.2,6.4-0.1
                c2.2-0.1,5.7-0.3,7.9-0.3l8-3.1l2.8-0.2l-2-2.6l1.9-1l0.3-3l4.9-0.8l4.5,0.4c1.7-0.1,5-0.2,6.7-0.3l6-3.5l3-3.3l6.3-3.5
                c1.5-1.6,4.5-4.9,5.9-6.6l-0.1-2.9l3.3-3.3c4.8-0.2,11-0.5,15.8-0.7c1.5-0.1,4.7-0.2,6.2-0.2l0.2,3.2l3.2-0.2
                c0.1,0.3,1.1,0.1,1.3,0.1l2.6,2.4l5.7-2.9l0.8,0.3l0.5-0.3l0.6-0.3l1.5,1.7l3.1,1.2l0.5,1.2l0.6-4.5l-1.2-2l0.9-3.6l1.5-2.8
                l2.8-0.1l-1-3.8l1.8-2.4l3.4-2.2l-0.7-2.2l-1.5,2.3L459.6,205.2z"/>    
    
        </g>
    </svg>
      <div class="hotspots">
        <div class="hotspot hot1" onclick="showPopup(1)"></div>
        <div class="hotspot hot2" onclick="showPopup(2)"></div>
        <div class="hotspot hot3" onclick="showPopup(3)"></div>
        <div class="hotspot hot4" onclick="showPopup(4)"></div>
        <div class="hotspot hot5" onclick="showPopup(5)"></div>
        <div class="hotspot hot6" onclick="showPopup(6)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I've tried moving the styles embedded in the SVG to the  section in the file, but it doesn't make any difference. The hover effect doesn't work; only the fill for the elements changes, and nothing else.

I'm also willing to remove the names from the SVG and add them in HTML to make it responsive.

Comment: Any chance you could turn this into a snippet? Just copy the SVG into the HTML part and the CSS into the, well, CSS part. Then we can see what you are seeing, that would be an enormous help.

Comment: @somethinghere Ok, the code in the question has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have placed a div with class `.hotspots` that sits on top of the SVG, it's this that's capturing the hover, to prevent this put `pointer-events: none` on this class.  You will also then want to add back `pointer-events` to the `.hotspot` class. `pointer-events: auto`

Also note you need to make sure you use `inline` svg, `img`tag won't work.

```js
function showPopup(i) {
  alert(`hotspot ${i}`);
}
```

```html
<style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .map-section {
      background-color: transparent;
      padding: 20px;
      min-height: 800px;
      max-width: 1200px;
    }

    .map-container {
      position: relative;
    }

    .hotspots {
      pointer-events: none;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .hotspot {
      pointer-events: auto;
      height: 18px;
      width: 18px;
      background-color: #ad0000;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      animation: pulsate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    }

    /*schweiz*/
    .hot1{
      top: 90%;
      left: 18%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*belgien*/
    .hot2{
      top: 39.5%;
      left: 11.5%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*niederlande*/
    .hot3{
      top: 27.5%;
      left: 11.5%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*osterreich*/
    .hot4{
      top: 83%;
      left: 52%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*deutschland*/
    .hot5{
      top: 42%;
      left: 53.5%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*polen*/
    .hot6{
      top: 38%;
      left: 74%;
      position: absolute;
    }

    /* styles for SVG elements */
    .schweiz, .belgien, .niederlande, .ostrreich, .deutschland, .polen {
      fill: #FFFFFF;
      stroke: #610000;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      transition: fill 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    }

    .schweiz:hover, .belgien:hover, .niederlande:hover, .ostrreich:hover, .deutschland:hover, .polen:hover {
      fill: #ad0000;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .noclick {
      fill: #E8E8E8;
      stroke: #7A0000;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }

    @keyframes pulsate {
      0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
      }
      50% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
      }
    }
  </style>

 <section class="map-section">
    <div class="map-container">
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 498.1 315.8"  xml:space="preserve">
        <g id="Layer_3">
            <path class="schweiz" d="M101.8,256.1c1.4,1.4,2.8,2.4,3.3,2.8l-0.1-3l6.6,2.7l3.5-0.2c5-0.2,10.6-0.5,15.6-0.7c0.3,0,6.5-0.3,6.6-0.3
                c0,0.3,0.2,3.2,0.2,3.4c1.7,0,4.6-0.2,6.2-0.2l0.1,2.9c1.4,0.6,4.3,1.9,5.7,2.5v2.9l-3.1,3.3l0.2,3.2c3.4,2,2.9,0.9,2.2,4.8
                c1.4,0.1,4.1-0.5,5.5-0.9c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1-0.1c1.5,0.9,4.4,3.5,5.7,4.8l9-0.4h0.7c0.1,2.9,0.3,6.8,0.4,9.7l-3.2,0.2l-3.3-2.8
                c-1.6,1.7-4.5,4.8-6.2,6.4c0.5,0.4,3.2,2.7,3.6,3c-4.1,3.7-2.1,4.1-6.5,0.3c-2.9,0.1-6.8,0.3-9.6,0.4c0-0.4-0.1-2.7-0.2-3.2
                l-0.5-0.5c-2.9-2.6-1.8-2.8-5.9-2.4c0,2,0.4,7.2,0.5,9.3l-3.5,0.1l-2.8,3.5l-3.3,3.2l0.2,3.1c-2.8-2.8-7-6.1-9.7-9.1
                c0-1.5-0.2-4.6-0.3-6.1c-0.4-0.4-3-2.6-3.4-3l-3.2,0.2l-3.1,3.3l0.2,3.2l-3.1,6.5l-3,0.2l-6.2,0.3l-3.5-3.2l-12.5,3.9
                c-1.8-1.8-4.6-4.3-6.5-6c0-3.8-1-3.1,2.8-3.3l-3.1-3l-0.1-3c1.7,0,4.4-0.2,6.2-0.2l-0.2-3.4l-3.5-6c-0.8,0-2.2,0.1-3,0.1l0.2,3.2
                c-0.4,0-3.1,0.2-3.5,0.2c-3.2,7.7-1.3,5.8-8.8,9.6c-0.3,0.6-3.5-6.2-3.7-6.1l2.9-6.3l6.1-6.4l-0.2-3.2l2.8-3.3l6.5-0.3l6.2-3.5
                l2.7-6.3l-0.2-3.2c0.1,0.1,3.3-3.6,3.4-3.2c1.6,1.6,4.9,4.5,6.6,5.9l0.1-0.3l2.6-6.2c0,0,3.2,2.9,3.4,3c0-0.2-0.2-2.9-0.2-3.2
                L101.8,256.1z"/>
            <path class="belgien" d="M71.1,181.4l-2-3.5c-0.1-1.6-0.3-4.8-0.3-6.4l3.2-3.1l3-3.6c0.3-0.3,2.7-0.3,3.1-0.3c-0.1-2.2-0.3-4.9-0.4-7.1
                c4.5-0.2,3,0.5,3-3.7c-0.2-3.8,0.5-2.9-3.2-2.8l2.8-6c0-2.5-0.3-6-0.4-8.5h-0.1l-0.2-3l-6.8-6.1c-1.7-1.5-5.2-4.6-6.8-6.1l-3.4,0.1
                l-3,3.1c0,0-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3l-3.6,0.1l-0.1-3.2L45.5,119c0-0.3-2.8,0-2.9,0l-3.2,3.1l0.2,3.2c-2.3,0.1-7.9,0.4-10.1,0.5
                c-4,0.1-2.9,0.8-3.3-3.1l-3.5-2.8l-3.4,0.2l-0.2-3.5l-3.4,0.2l-3.2,3.6L9,117.1l0.2,3.4l-6.3,3.2l0.1,3.2c0.1,1.6,0.3,4.6,0.3,6.2
                l3.3,3c0.4,0,0.3,2.3,0.3,2.6v0.7l3.1-0.2l3.1-0.1h0.2c0.1,1.7,0.2,4.7,0.3,6.4c1.6-0.1,4.9-0.2,6.5-0.3c0.4-0.3,0.2,2.9,0.3,3v0.3
                l3.7,6.1c2.9-0.2,6.9-0.2,9.8-0.5c0.1,2.1,0.4,7.6,0.5,9.7l-3,2.9l-0.2,0.2l3.5,3.3c1.7-0.1,5-0.2,6.7-0.3l-0.2-3.5l3.4-0.2
                l0.1,3.5l3.3,2.7l0.2,0.2c0,0.3,0.1,3,0.2,3.2l3.3,2.9l0.2,0.2l0.1,2.4v0.6l3.2-0.1c1.7,1.6,5.2,4.7,7,6.1l0.2,3.2l3.2-3.4l3.4-0.1
                l0.7-0.4C69.7,187.2,71.3,181.5,71.1,181.4z"/>
            <path class="noclick" d="M82.7,188.4c3.9-0.2,2.9,0.4,2.8-3.3c-0.1-1.8-0.2-4.5-0.3-6.3c-0.1-0.7-0.1-2.7-0.2-3.4
                c-1.7-1.5-5.1-4.5-6.7-6c0-1.2-0.2-3.7-0.2-4.9l-2.6,0.1c-0.4-0.3-3.3,3.6-3.5,3.8l-3.2,3.1c0.1,1.6,0.2,4.8,0.3,6.4l2,3.5
                c0.1,0.1-1.5,5.8-0.8,5.5c3.9,0.8,9.3,2.5,13.3,3C83.4,189.5,83,188.8,82.7,188.4z"/>
            <path class="niederlande" d="M55.8,121.5l0.1,3.2c0.2-0.1,3.9,0.1,3.8-0.4l2.8-3.1h0.2l3.4-0.1l3.3,3c2.3,1.9,8,7.1,10.3,9.2l0.2,3
                c0.2,0.1,0-1,0.1-1c0.2-0.3,6.3-2.9,5.8-3.5l0.5-0.2l-0.2-3.2c-0.1-3.4-0.4-8.7-0.6-12.1l5.9-3.4l9.5-3.5l3.1,2.9
                c2.9-0.1,6.8-0.3,9.6-0.5l3.2-0.1l0.1-0.4c0.3,0.1,2.7-9.4,2.9-9.5l-0.2-3.2l-3.1-2.8L119,93c-0.2-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.4-0.7
                c-0.1-3.3-0.5-8.7-0.6-12l3-0.2v-0.4h0.2c-0.1-2.7-0.4-6.4-0.5-9.1l2.7-3.1l0,0l0.4-0.4l-2.1-1.8l-2.6,2.4l-3.2,0.2l-0.6-12.7
                c-1.7,0.1-5,0.2-6.7,0.3l-3,3.6l-6.6,3.3c-0.1-1.6-0.2-4.9-0.3-6.5l-3.4,3.6L93,59.6l-3.4,0.2L83,63.1l-3.2,3.4
                c0.1,1.5,0.2,4.6,0.3,6.2c0.1,3.6,0.5,9.2,0.7,12.9l-6.2,6.5c-1.7,0-5,0.2-6.7,0.3l-0.3-6.2l3.2-3.5l-3.4,0.1
                c1.6-1.6,4.8-4.9,6.4-6.5l-0.2-3.2L70,70c-9,0.4-5.5-0.9-9.8,6.8l0.3,6.2l-3,3.5l0.1,3L54,89.7l0.2,3.2l-3,3.4l-6.7,0.3l0.3,6.4
                c3.8,0,3.3-1.4,3.5,2.8l-6.3,3.5l-0.3-6.2l-3.6,0.2c0.1,3.4,0.5,8.9,0.6,12.4l3.6-0.2l3.1,3.1l0.2,0.2L55.8,121.5z"/>
            <path class="ostrreich" d="M327.1,244.9L327.1,244.9h0.2l2.3-1.1c0-0.4-3.6-4-3.9-4.4l0.9-2.8c-2.5-3.5-1.6-2.6-5.7-2.5
                c-0.8-0.2-2.5-0.5-3.2-0.7l-5-2.3l-1-1.9l-2-1.8l-1.8-2.7c-2.1-0.3-7.4,0.3-9.5,0.3c-0.7-0.5-2.9-2.7-3.7-3
                c-3.5,0.2-9,0.4-12.5,0.6c-0.8,0.7-2.4,2.3-2.8,3.3l0.1,3.2l-3,3.3c-3.1,0.1-9.5,0.4-12.7,0.6l-1.3-0.6l-2.4-2.2
                c-0.6-0.2-2.5-0.1-3.1-0.1l0.2,3.2c-2.9,0.1-6.9,0.4-9.8,0.5l0.1,3c-1.4,1.6-4.3,5-5.7,6.6l-9.9,0.4c0.1,2,0.4,7.3,0.5,9.3
                c0.7,0.6,3,2.7,3.6,3.3l0.1,2.9l0.2,3.2c0.5,0.5,2.7,2.6,3.1,3c0.1,1.6,0.3,4.8,0.3,6.3l-3,0.2l0.2,3l-0.9-0.7v0.1
                c-0.4-0.4-2.2-1.8-2.7-2.2c-0.1-1.6-0.2-4.7-0.3-6.3c-0.1-0.1-6-2.7-6.3-2.9l-3,0.1l0.2,3.2l-3.6-3c-3.5,0.2-9.2,0.4-12.7,0.6
                l-3.1,3.3l-3,0.1l-3.4,0.2l-3.2-3l-3.2,3.3c-1.6,0.1-4.8,0.2-6.5,0.3c0-0.6-0.2-2.6-0.1-3.2c0,0-5.9-2.8-6.2-2.9l-3.2,6.5l-3,0.1
                c-4.2,3.6-2.1,4.2-6.5,0.3L163,269c-0.4-0.4-1.2-1-1.5-1.4c-1.2-1-4-3.6-5.2-4.6l-3.2,0.2l-2.9,3.3l-0.9-0.4v2.9l0.8-0.1l2.7,3.1
                l-0.7,2.2l2.4,1.2l-0.3,3.8c1.5,0.9,4.4,3.5,5.7,4.8c2.6-0.1,10.2-0.5,12.7-0.6c0.2,0,3.1-0.1,3.2-0.1c0.1,1.7,0.3,4.6,0.3,6.3
                c1.6-0.1,4.8-0.2,6.5-0.3l6-3.4l-0.2-3.2l3.2-0.2l3.4,3c2.9-0.1,6.8-0.4,9.7-0.5l6.2-0.3c1.6,1.4,4.7,4.3,6.3,5.7l0.5,0.4l0.2,3
                l3.2,3c0.6,0.6,2.8,2.2,3.5,2.8c1.6-0.1,4.7-0.2,6.2-0.3c2.1-0.1,7.4-0.3,9.6-0.4c0.8,0.8,2.5,2.4,3.4,3.2l2.8-0.2
                c0.2,0,0.7,0,0.8,0.2l5.5-1.9l2.8-0.1l3.9,4.2c1.8-0.1,4.6-0.2,6.4-0.3l3.8,2.6l0.7-2.8l4.4-1.9l3.9,0.7c-0.5-0.6,2.1-5,2.3-5.6
                h0.6c4-0.2,8.9-0.4,12.9-0.6c2.7,0.2,5.8-1.2,8.3-2.1l3.7,0.7l4-3.5c0.1-0.1,2.2-5.4,2.5-5c-0.1-0.3,2.9-0.2,3-0.3l2.6-6.3
                l-0.3-6.1h0.5v-0.4c3.4-0.4,3.1,0.9,2.9-2.9l-0.2-3l-3.6-3l-0.2-3.2h0.4V261c0.5,0,3.5-0.1,3.8-0.2l2.9-1.6l-0.5,1.5
                c0.3-0.2,0.1,1.2,0.2,1.2l3.2,0.7c0-0.2-0.4-1.8-0.1-1.9v-0.2l2.6-3c-1.4-3.4-3-8.8-5.2-11.7L327.1,244.9z"/>
            <path class="noclick" d="M146.3,272.2l0.2,3.2c3.4,2,2.9,0.9,2.2,4.8c1.4,0.1,4.2-0.5,5.6-0.9c0-0.1,0.3-3.8,0.3-3.9l-2.4-1.2l0.7-2.2
                l-2.7-3.1l-0.8,0.1C149.4,268.9,146.3,272.2,146.3,272.2z"/>
            <path class="deutschland" d="M102.5,256.7c0.5,0.5,2.1,1.8,2.6,2.2l-0.1-3l6.6,2.7l3.5-0.2c5-0.2,10.6-0.5,15.6-0.7c0.3,0,6.5-0.3,6.6-0.3
                c0,0.3,0.2,3.2,0.2,3.4c1.7,0,4.5-0.2,6.2-0.2l0.1,2.9c1.8,0.8,4.8,2.1,6.6,2.9l2.9-3.3l3.2-0.2c1.5,1.4,4.3,3.9,5.8,5.2l0.9,0.8
                l3.2-0.1c4.4,3.9,2.2,3.3,6.5-0.3l3-0.1l3.2-6.5c0.3,0.1,6.1,2.9,6.2,2.9c-0.1,0.6,0.2,2.6,0.1,3.2c1.6-0.1,4.8-0.2,6.5-0.3
                l3.2-3.3l3.2,3l3.4-0.2l3-0.1l3.1-3.3c3.5-0.1,9.2-0.4,12.7-0.6l3.6,3l-0.2-3.2l3-0.1c0.3,0.2,6.2,2.8,6.3,2.9
                c0,1.6,0.2,4.7,0.3,6.3c1,0.8,2.7,2.1,3.6,2.8l-0.2-3c4.1-0.2,2.8,0.3,2.8-3.5l-0.2-3l-0.6-0.6l-2.5-2.4c-0.1-1.5-0.2-4.6-0.3-6.1
                c-0.6-0.6-3.1-2.7-3.6-3.3c-0.1-1.9-0.3-7.3-0.5-9.3l9.9-0.4c1.4-1.7,4.3-5,5.7-6.6l-0.1-3c2.9-0.1,6.9-0.3,9.8-0.5l-0.2-3.2
                l-2-2.6l-3-3.7c-1.5-1-4-3.4-5-4.9l-0.3-0.4l-3.1,0.1l-3.3-2.8c-1.8-3-5.3-9.1-7-12.2l-3.9-3.1c0.2-2.1-0.3-6.9-0.6-9l-2.5-3.5
                l-3.8-2.5l-0.3-6.4l-2.6-0.2l-4.1-5.6l-0.4-7c0.5-0.3,3.6,2.9,3.9,3.2l0.2,3.2l5.9-3.6c0.2-0.1,3.4,3,3.6,3.2l5.9-0.6l0.3-0.1
                l4.2-2.8l1.8-0.7c0.3,0,3.2,0,3.4-0.1l2.3-3.9l3.9-0.2l8.4-5.9c1.8-1.4,4.9-4.5,6.3-6.3l6.7-3.6c0.3,0.1,3.4,3,3.8,3.2l0.2,3.2
                l2.6-0.3c0-0.2,3.1-3.2,3.2-3.4c-0.1-1.8-0.5-10.3-0.6-12.2l2.8-3.3c-3.6,0-2.9,1-3.1-2.8c-0.2-3.9-0.6-11.7-0.7-15.7l-3.8-6.2
                l-0.1-3.2L276,104l3.3-3.3l-3.2,0.1h-0.2l-3.1-3l-0.1-3l-3.4-3l-3.6-6.2c1.7-1.5,4.7-4.8,6.2-6.6c-0.1-1.5-0.2-4.6-0.3-6.1
                c-0.3-4.5-0.2-10.8-0.5-15.4l-9.7,0.4l-0.3-6.4l-0.3-6.3c-2.2,0.2-7.5,0.3-9.6,0.5l-0.2-3.2l-3.2-2.8c-0.2-4.2,0.5-3.1-3.5-3
                l-2.9,3.3c-1.6,0.1-4.9,0.2-6.5,0.3c-3.2,1.6-9.5,4.9-12.5,6.7l-3.2-3l0.2,3.2c-3.6,0.1-9.3,0.4-12.9,0.6l-6.6-2.9l3.5-0.2
                c-0.1-3.7-0.7-2.8,2.9-3.1c-0.1-1.6-0.2-4.9-0.3-6.5c-1.6,0.1-4.9,0.2-6.5,0.3l-2.8,3.5l-3.5-6.2c-1.6,0.1-4.8,0.2-6.4,0.3
                l-0.2-3.2c-1.6,0.1-4.8,0.2-6.4,0.3l-0.2-3.2l3.2-3.3c-1.8-1.4-5.3-4.3-6.9-5.9l-1-0.8l-1.4,1.3l1.3-1.4l-2.2-1.7
                c-0.1-0.1-5.8,0.5-5.6,0h-0.6l-2.9-2.6l-2.8,0.1c0-0.9-0.2-0.6-0.9-0.6c0.1,2.1,0.3,7.5,0.5,9.5l3.1,2.8l0.2,3.2l-6.3,3.5l-3,0.1
                c0.3,3.8-0.8,3.2,3.2,3c0.1,1.6,0.2,4.8,0.3,6.3l6.6,2.9l-2.8,3.1l2.5,1.8l3.4,4.8l-1.7,3.4l-1.7-2.9l-1.5-3.1
                c-3.1,0.2-7.5-0.5-10.6-0.4c0.2,3.6,0.4,9.2,0.6,12.7l-3,3.3l0.1,2.9l-3.5-5.7c-0.1-1.6-0.2-4.8-0.3-6.4l-3.2,0.1l0.2,3.2l-3,0.1
                l-0.2-3.2l2.9-3.3l-6.6-2.9c-4.6,0.2-11.3,0.5-15.8,0.7l0.2,3.2l-3.1,3.3c0.3,4-0.6,3.1,3.4,3l0.2,3.2c0.8,0.6,2.6,2.1,3.3,2.8
                l-0.4,0.4l0,0l-2.7,3.1c0.1,2.7,0.3,6.4,0.5,9.1h-0.2V80l-3,0.2c0.1,3.3,0.5,8.7,0.6,12l-0.4,0.5v0.2l-2.5,2.8l3.1,2.8l0.2,3.2
                l-2.7,9.4c-0.2,0-0.2,0.4-0.2,0.5c-4,0.2-8.8,0.4-12.8,0.6l-3.1-2.9l-9.5,3.5l-5.9,3.4l0.2,2.8c0.1,3.5,0.4,9,0.6,12.4l-0.5,0.2
                v0.4l-5.8,3.1v1c0.1,2.5,0.3,6,0.4,8.5l-2.8,6c3.7,0,3-1,3.2,2.8c-0.1,4.2,1.5,3.6-3,3.7c0.2,3.9,0.4,8.1,0.6,12
                c1.6,1.5,5.1,4.5,6.7,6.1c0.2,3,0.3,6.6,0.5,9.7c0,3.7,1.2,3.1-2.8,3.3c1.9,3.1,5,8.6,6.8,11.7l3.4,3l6.3,2.9l6.7-0.3l3.1,2.8
                c1.6-0.1,4.9-0.2,6.5-0.3l3,3l0.3,0.3c-2.1,2.3-7.1,7.6-9.2,9.7l-2.7,6.5l0.1,3l-3.3,3.3c0.1,2,0.4,7.2,0.5,9.2l0.2,3.2l-3.1,3.3
                c0.1,1.6,0.2,4.7,0.3,6.2l0.2,0.1L102.5,256.7z"/>
            <path class="polen" d="M492.1,148.9l-2.4-1l-0.2-4l2.3-1.2l-5.9-6.9l-2.5-4.6l-4.7-3c2.1-3.2,2-2-0.2-5l1.7-9.2
                c-0.3-0.3-0.8-0.9-1.1-1.2c-0.5-1.3,1.3-10.2,1.5-11.7l-5.7-1l-2.7-3.7l11.4-8.4c0-0.4,1.2-3.1,1.2-3.4l0.7-2.2
                c-0.2-2.2-0.1-11-1.5-12.8l-1.2-3.4c-1.2-1.4-4.5-5.5-5.7-7l-1.9-2.2l-0.4-9.1l-2.5-2l-1.3-4.6c0-1-0.3-5.8-0.3-6.7l-7.1-5l-4.8-1
                l-5.6-3.5L453,25c-0.1,0,2.1-3.6,2.2-3.7l-3.5,0.2l1-0.5l0.9-4.5c-0.5-2.2-1.3-6-2.5-8l-2.6-5.2l-5.7-1.7l-5,1.9L435.2,7l-1.1,1.3
                c-2.4,0.1-7.8,0.4-10.1,0.5h-0.8l-1-2.5l-2.7-3.5c-1.8,0.5-6,1.4-7.9,1.2c0.2,4-0.3,2.8,3.4,2.8l-2.9,6.3l-3.1,3.3l-6.2,0.3
                c-0.2-2.8-0.3-6.6-0.5-9.3L393,14l0.2,3.2l-5.4,4.7l5.7,1.7l0.2,2.9l-3,3.5l-3,0.2c0.2,2.7,0.3,6.5,0.5,9.2
                c-2.1,0.1-7.6,0.3-9.7,0.5l-0.1-3.2l-3.2,0.1l-9.3,3.6l-3.5-3c-0.2-2.8-0.3-6.7-0.5-9.5l-3.2-2.8l-0.2-3.2l-9.7,0.5l-3,3.3
                l-3.2,0.2l-6.4-2.9l-3,3.3l-3.2,0.2c0.2,4,0.5,2.7-3.1,3.1l-3.1,3.5l-3.4-3.2c-1.3,1.8-4.3,5.2-5.9,6.8l-3,3.1l-3.2,0.2l-3,3.3
                l-3.2,0.2c0,3.8,1.1,3.1-2.9,3.3c-2.1,0.1-7.6,0.3-9.7,0.5l-6.2,3.5l-2.9,6.5l-2.8,3.1l3.1,2.8l0.2,3.4l-0.9-0.4l-4.7,0.2l-3.6-4.2
                c-0.4,5.5,0.2,11.6,0.4,17.1c-1.4,1.8-4.5,5.1-6.2,6.6l3.6,6.2l3.4,3l0.1,3l3.1,3h0.2l3.2-0.1l-3.5,3l0.2,3.2l0.1,3.2l3.8,6.2
                c0.2,4,0.6,11.7,0.7,15.7c0.2,3.7-0.6,2.9,3.1,2.8l-2.8,3.3c0.1,2,0.5,10.4,0.6,12.2c0.3-0.2,1.4-1.8,1.6-2.2
                c0.1,0,4.5-0.9,4.6-0.9l3.1-0.1c0.1,3.5,0.5,8.8,0.6,12.2l3.2-0.2l3.4,3l3.2-0.2l6.4,2.9h0.4l6-0.3l3.4,3c-1.5,1.7-4.6,5-6.1,6.6
                h0.5l6-0.3c0.1-0.1,3.3,2.8,3.4,2.8l3.5,6c0-0.5-0.5-3.1-0.6-3.6l0.8-1.6l2.4-1.5l3.3,0.4l-3.4-1.3l-0.3-2c2.3,0.6,7.6,0,10,0
                l3.4,2.8c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.7,0.4-0.9l2.7-2.4c2,2.7,7.3,10.3,10,12.2l6.6,2.7l6.4-0.3l3.2,3c1.7,1.5,5.1,4.3,6.7,5.8h0.4l6-0.2
                l3.4,3.2c0.3-0.1,0-1.5,0.1-1.7l2.7-2.5l2.4-1.2c0.2-0.1,4.3-1.2,4.2-1.5l0.1,0.1l3.1,2.7l0.3,6.3l0.4-0.4v-1l1.8-1.6l-0.1-4.4l7-3
                l3.3,3.5l3-0.1l3.1-3.1c0.1,2,0.3,7.3,0.4,9.2c0.3,0.3,6.5-4.3,6.8-4.5l4-0.4c1-1.2,3.5-3.9,4.6-5.1l3.7,6.2h0.2l2.8-0.1
                c3.1,2.5,7.1,6.2,10.1,8.8c0.9,0,2.3-0.1,3.2-0.1c1.3-0.1,4-0.2,5.3-0.2h0.9l1.2,4.6c0.8-1.2,2.4-3.6,3.2-4.8l-0.4-3.3l0.7-2.6
                c-0.1-1.6-0.2-4.8-0.3-6.3c0.4-2.6,1.5-8.4,2.3-10.9l2.6-3.7l3.4-1c1-2.2,3.2-7.1,4.3-9.1l6.2-5.8l6.2,0.5l3.5-2.7l2-6.9
                L492.1,148.9z"/>
            <path class="noclick" d="M278.7,153.6c0.1,0.3-2.7,0.4-2.8,0.5l-0.2-3.2c-0.2-0.3-3.7-3-3.8-3.2l-6.7,3.6c-1.4,1.8-4.5,4.9-6.3,6.3
                l-8.4,5.9l-3.9,0.2l-2.3,3.9c-0.2,0.1-3.1,0.1-3.4,0.1l-1.8,0.7l-4.2,2.8l-0.3,0.1l-5.9,0.6c-0.2-0.2-3.3-3.3-3.6-3.2l-5.9,3.6
                l-0.2-3.2c-0.3-0.2-3.5-3.4-3.9-3.2l0.4,7l4.1,5.6l2.6,0.2l0.3,6.4l3.8,2.5l2.5,3.5c0.4,2.2,0.7,6.9,0.6,9l3.9,3.1
                c1.7,3.1,5.2,9.2,7,12.2l3.3,2.8l3.1-0.1c0.1,0.2,2.2,2.7,2.4,2.9c2.9,2,5.8,5.9,7.9,8.7c0.2,0.1,3-0.1,3.1,0.1l2.4,2.2
                c0.9,1,6.4,0.3,7.5,0.3l6.4-0.3l3-3.3l-0.1-3.2c0.4-1,2-2.6,2.8-3.3c3.6-0.2,9.1-0.4,12.7-0.6c0.5,0.5,3,2.5,3.5,3
                c2.1-0.1,7.3-0.4,9.4-0.5c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1l1.8,2.7l2,1.8l1,1.9c1,0.5,5.8,2.7,6.9,2.7l2.4-5.6l0.4-5l2.6-4.3
                c2.5-1,7.5-2.7,10.1-3.3l6.6-5l3-0.9l3.2,1.2c1.8,1.8,5.7,4.3,7.9,5.4l3.9-0.1l4.5-3.5c1.7-3,5.4-8.9,7.3-11.8l3.6-3.1l1-1.7
                l-2.9-2.6c-1.8-1.4-5.1-4.5-6.7-6l-6.4,0.3l-6.6-2.7c-2.6-1.9-8.1-9.5-10-12.2l-2.7,2.4c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.8-0.4,0.9l-3.4-2.8
                c-2.4,0-7.7,0.7-10,0l0.3,2l3.4,1.3l-3.3-0.4l-2.4,1.5l-0.8,1.6c0.1,0.5,0.6,3.1,0.6,3.6l-3.5-6c0,0-3.3-2.9-3.4-2.8l-6,0.3h-0.5
                c1.5-1.6,4.6-5,6.1-6.6l-3.4-3l-6,0.3h-0.4l-6.4-2.9L298,162l-3.4-3l-3.2,0.2c-0.1-3.4-0.4-8.8-0.6-12.2c-1.9-0.1-5.8,0.6-7.7,1
                C282.5,149.9,279.9,152.3,278.7,153.6z"/>
            <path class="noclick" d="M459.6,205.2c-2.9,0.1-6.3,0.3-9.2,0.4c-1.9-1.1-5.2-4.6-7-6l-3.3-2.8l-2.8,0.1c-0.3,0.5-3.8-6.2-4-6.2
                c-1.1,1.2-3.6,3.9-4.6,5.1l-4,0.4l-6,4.3l-0.4,0.3v-0.1l-0.5,0.1c-0.1-1.9-0.3-7.3-0.4-9.2l-3.1,3.1l-3,0.1l-3.3-3.5l-7,3l0.1,4.4
                l-1.8,1.6v1l-0.4,0.4l-0.3-6.3c-0.2-0.1-3.2-3.1-3.4-2.6c-1.6,0.4-5,1.5-6.4,2.4l-2.7,2.5c0,0.2,0.2,1.5-0.1,1.7l-3.4-3.2
                c-0.3-0.1-6.7,0.5-6.6,0.1l-1,1.7l-3.6,3.1l-4,6.2l-3.3,5.5l-4.5,3.5l-3.9,0.1c-2.3-1.1-6.1-3.6-7.9-5.4l-3.2-1.2l-3,0.9l-6.6,5
                c-2.6,0.5-7.7,2.3-10.1,3.3l-2.6,4.3l-0.4,5l-2.4,5.6c0.9,0.5,4.1,0.2,5.1,0.1l2,2.7l-0.9,2.8c0.4,0.4,3.7,4,4.1,4.3
                c-1.2,0.6-3.4,1.5-4.6,2.1l1.5,2.2l-0.6-1.4l7.3,4.7l0.5,0.4h0.9l3.1,2.6l2.2-0.1c1.7,1.3,4.9,4.2,6.4,5.7c0.1,0.4,6.1-0.2,6.4-0.1
                c2.2-0.1,5.7-0.3,7.9-0.3l8-3.1l2.8-0.2l-2-2.6l1.9-1l0.3-3l4.9-0.8l4.5,0.4c1.7-0.1,5-0.2,6.7-0.3l6-3.5l3-3.3l6.3-3.5
                c1.5-1.6,4.5-4.9,5.9-6.6l-0.1-2.9l3.3-3.3c4.8-0.2,11-0.5,15.8-0.7c1.5-0.1,4.7-0.2,6.2-0.2l0.2,3.2l3.2-0.2
                c0.1,0.3,1.1,0.1,1.3,0.1l2.6,2.4l5.7-2.9l0.8,0.3l0.5-0.3l0.6-0.3l1.5,1.7l3.1,1.2l0.5,1.2l0.6-4.5l-1.2-2l0.9-3.6l1.5-2.8
                l2.8-0.1l-1-3.8l1.8-2.4l3.4-2.2l-0.7-2.2l-1.5,2.3L459.6,205.2z"/>    
    
        </g>
    </svg>
      <div class="hotspots">
        <div class="hotspot hot1" onclick="showPopup(1)"></div>
        <div class="hotspot hot2" onclick="showPopup(2)"></div>
        <div class="hotspot hot3" onclick="showPopup(3)"></div>
        <div class="hotspot hot4" onclick="showPopup(4)"></div>
        <div class="hotspot hot5" onclick="showPopup(5)"></div>
        <div class="hotspot hot6" onclick="showPopup(6)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Thanks, man. No way I could have found it by myself.